# How to use Win_Shell to copy paste

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-winshell

I am writing a code which needs enter, copying and pasting:

so far I have managed to do the enter with this

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
```

is there a way to do the same for ctrl c and v

pyperclip has not worked well but this has magnifiecently so I just wanted to ask.

Comment: where do you want to copy from? what do you want to copy? Where do you want to paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is use pynput:

Here is something I did. w/ if statement

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller


        if tm == b'RickRoll':

            keyboard = Controller()
            while True:
                os.startfile("Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp4")

                while True:
                    keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
                    keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)
                    time.sleep(0.1)
               

                if tm == 'Stop':
                    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
                    keyboard.press(Key.alt)
                    keyboard.press(Key.delete)

                    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
                    keyboard.release(Key.alt)
                    keyboard.release(Key.delete)

                    keyboard.press(Key.)
                    keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)


                    keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
                    keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)



                    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
                    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` represents as CTRL key, so:

```py
shell.SendKeys("^c")
```

or

```py
shell.SendKeys("^v")
```

for other keys see [this](https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/wsh/wshshell-sendkeys.html)